# Subreport - Error in the location specification of the Report

Tags: c#, rdlc, subreport

I'm having the following error that I detail below:

***"The 'Encabezado' subreport could not be found at the specified location SPECIFIC ROUTE\ Encabezado.rdlc. Verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct."***

```
InitializeComponent();
string nombreSP = "XXX_SP_REPORTING_SERVICES_DESPACHOS";
DataSet ds = frmListClass.ObtenerDS(parametrosXML, nombreSP);
string[] nodoParametro = frmListClass.ParsearParametros(parametrosXML);
int[] cantDecimales = frmListClass.ObtenerCantDecimales(parametrosXML);

ReportParameter p1  = new ReportParameter("Base", nodoParametro[0]);
ReportParameter p2  = new ReportParameter("User", nodoParametro[1]);
ReportParameter p3  = new ReportParameter("Sistema", nodoParametro[3]);
ReportParameter p4  = new ReportParameter("Caratula", nodoParametro[4]);
ReportParameter p5  = new ReportParameter("FormatoQRP", nodoParametro[5]);            
ReportParameter p6  = new ReportParameter("dcmlCant", cantDecimales[0].ToString());
ReportParameter p7  = new ReportParameter("dcmlCantTalle", cantDecimales[1].ToString());
ReportParameter p8  = new ReportParameter("dcmlPrecio", cantDecimales[2].ToString());
ReportParameter p9  = new ReportParameter("dcmlImporte", cantDecimales[3].ToString());



ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource(nombreSP, ds.Tables[0]);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
string rutaEncabezado = @"D:\\BASCS-ReportingServices\\BAS-ReportingServices\\BCSLDSPT\\Encabezado.rdlc";
string rutaRDLC = @"D:\\BASCS-ReportingServices\\BAS-ReportingServices\\BCSLDSPT\\Report1.rdlc";
Stream subReport = File.OpenRead(rutaEncabezado);
Stream report = File.OpenRead(rutaRDLC);            
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(report);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("Encabezado", subReport);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(AgregarEncabezado);                                                                     
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9/*, p10, p11, p12, p13*/ });
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();                        

Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string filenameExtension;
byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings);

string rutaArchivo = frmListClass.ObtenerRutaPDF(bytes);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(rutaArchivo);


void AgregarEncabezado(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        string Parametros = "1, 1, NULL, 1";            
        string cadenaConexion = "Data Source=SRVDESARROLLO7\\BASCS; Initial Catalog=bascsreport ;User Id=sa; Password=sa";
        string cadenaComandoSQL = frmListClass.SeteosSQL + frmListClass.SP_Encabezado + " " + Parametros;

        SqlConnection ConexionSQL = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        ConexionSQL.Open();
        SqlCommand ComandoSQL = new SqlCommand(cadenaComandoSQL, ConexionSQL);
        ComandoSQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        ComandoSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@monoemp, @codempusu, @tituloinf, @whereemp", Parametros);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = ComandoSQL;
        DataSet dsEncabezado = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dsEncabezado, Parametros);
        ConexionSQL.Close();

        ReportDataSource dataSourceEncabezado = new ReportDataSource("XXX_SP_REPORTING_PARAMETROS_EMP", dsEncabezado.Tables[0]);
        e.DataSources.Add(dataSourceEncabezado);

    }
```

I need to be able to pass to the main report the Subreport (Header), since in it I have parameters that are shown in the Header that are repeated in almost all reports. The subreport is in another project, can this be the problem?

Can the SubreportProcessingEventHandler be ill-defined?

Please I need help!!

Comment: Why can't you just pass the instance reportViewer1 to the 2nd project?

Comment: Hello! How could I do that?

Comment: Just pass it as a parameter in the call.  Why are you using a Stream to pass data to subreport.  Wouldn't it make sense just to send the reportviewer?  The add data to the reportviewer in the subreport.

Comment: You mean something like this:public ReportViewer GetReport(ReportViewer report)
        {
            report = reportViewer1;
            return report;
         }

Comment: I don't know why you would need to cast, nor return the report.  When you pass an class object to a method it is passed by reference. public void GetReport(reportViewer1)

Comment: Could you pass me the code of what you are telling me? I would appreciate it.

Comment: It would be necessary to encapsulate the heading in other rdlc so as not to be repeating them in all the reports, but they will show different things due to the input parameters of each Report in question.
It is important that the subreport be the Header, since the other flow will come from the other report.

Comment: As I said, pass the report by reference.  Call the method AddSubreport(ReportViewer reportViewer, string option).  The option can be used as necessary to indicate the flow.